# Google sheet Query last 7 rows of a table

Tags: google-sheets-query

I have a large table (sample sheet included here) of data where I use a query to total and average columns C and D based on the day of the week, but I'd also like to include into this query a total for the last 7 rows (The last week) grouped by column A (day of the week).

This is the query I'm using:

```
=Query(A2:D,"SELECT A, sum(C), sum(D), Avg(C), Avg(D)
WHERE A <> ''
GROUP BY A
ORDER BY A
LABEL A 'Day',sum(C) 'Total Checked In',sum(D) 'Total Checked Out',Avg(C) 'Average Checked In',Avg(D) 'Average Checked Out'")
```

Can anyone help me out to add a final column to show just the last 7 rows?

Here is the sample sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18PMhuBrZLscYufS8eonViZfbz2kstyyWFzmt8cZlRBE/edit?usp=sharing

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out in case anyone is interested:

```
=QUERY(A2:D30,"Select sum(C), sum(D) Where B >= date '" & text(P1,"yyyy-mm-dd") & "' group by A Label sum(C) 'This Week Checked In', sum(D) 'This Week Checked Out'")
```

I used this formula to get the last cell (date) `=INDEX(B3:B30,COUNTA(B3:B30),1)`

Then deducted a week in P1 which is used in the query.